# Isn't this very large set excluded by the axiom of regularity (foundation)?

Tags: set-theory

The axiom of regularity is
$$
\forall x:(x \neq \emptyset \to \exists z \in x:z \cap x = \emptyset)
$$
and the negation is
$$
\exists x:(x \neq \emptyset \wedge \forall z \in x:z \cap x \neq \emptyset)
$$
A 'set' $x$ constructed as follows
$$
x := \{z_1,z_2,z_3,\dots\}; \qquad
\begin{cases}
\emptyset \notin x, \\
z_1 = \{z_2,\dots\} = \{\{z_3,\dots\},\dots\} = \dots, \\
z_2 = \{z_3,\dots\} = \{\{z_4,\dots\},\dots\} = \dots, \\
\dots
\end{cases}
$$
should satisfy the negated statement of the axiom, since
$$
x \cap z_n = \{z_{n+1}\} \neq \emptyset, \qquad x \ni z_1 \ni z_2 \ni z_3 , \dots
$$
Now this is a large set that the axiom of reguarity rules out *but* the set
$$
x' = x \cup \{\emptyset\} = \{\emptyset,z_1,z_2,z_3,\dots\}
$$
is still larger with infinite descending $\ni$-series and yet not ruled out, since
$$
\exists z \in x':z \cap x' = \emptyset, \qquad \text{namely $z = \emptyset$}
$$
Is there a mistake in this reasoning ?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Any set that has the empty set as a member is not an instance of violation of Foundation.

Comment: $x$ is not necessarily "large"'. Without Foundation it is consistent that some $x$ satisfies $x=\{x\}=z_1=z_2=z_3=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake in your reasoning! The axiom of regularity alone cannot rule out your larger set although it does contain an infinite descending membership chain. Everything depends on whether your theory prove the existence of a transitive closure for every set. If it doesn't (like Zermelo), then adding regularity as a single sentence like the one you wrote won't be sufficient to rule out infinite descending membership chains. But for the set you wrote, one can easily negate it in Zermelo, since by separation I can retrieve the set $x$ from $x'$ and this would negate Regularity. In order to get rid of having infinite descending membership chains in a theory like Zermelo (or any theory that doesn't prove transitive closures), you need to add Regularity as a schema! $$ \forall \vec{p} \, (\exists x.\phi(x) \to \exists z:\phi(z) \land \forall y (\phi(y) \to y \not \in z))$$; for every formula $\phi$.

The transitive closure of a set $x$ is a set that contains all elements of $x$, elements of elements of $x$, elements of elements of elements of $x$, etc... Formally that is:

$TC(x)=\{ y: \forall \ trs \ t( x \subseteq t \to y \in t) \}$

Where: $trs(t) \iff \forall z \in t (z \subseteq t)$

In nutshell: the axiom of Regularity alone by itself cannot negate existence of $x'$, but together with the other axioms of set theory, especially Separation $x'$ cannot exist. And if you want to get rid of infinite descending membership, then you need to add Regularity as a schema if your theory doesn't prove transitive closures, if it does, you can add it as a single axiom.

Comment: If you retrieve $x$ from $x'$, then $x$ is ruled out by Regularity, but $x'$ is still there not negated in ZF, right ?

Comment: @Physor, No! $x'$ is NOT there, because its existence leads to the existence of $x$ [through Separation] which negate an axiom of the system namely Regularity as you wrote. By the way for ZF we can prove transitive closures and so we can add Regularity as a single axiom because this would be equivalent to the above schema. But for Zermelo, those forms of Regularity won't be equivalent. A simpler example suppose you work in Zermelo minus Separation, then your $x'$ can be there!

Comment: Could you please specify more explicitly the scope of quantifier $\exists z$ in the schema above, I think it should be $\exists z:(\phi(z)\wedge (\forall y:( \phi(y) \to y \notin z)))$, right ? because the last $z$ in your answer doesn't seem to be in the scope of the quantifier, taking into account of priority rules

Comment: @Physor it is the the whole formula after $\exists z$, the last $z$ is within the scope of that quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that your theory is not "just" the axiom of regularity, as witnessed by your attempt to *construct* sets, which generally require additional axioms to justify why the construction results in a set.

If we look at $x\cup\{\varnothing\}$, it's true that it has an element which is disjoint from itself, but if you allow even the most basic Separation axioms, you can construct $x$ out of $x\cup\{\varnothing\}$ by simply look at $\{y\in x\cup\{\varnothing\}\mid\exists z(z\in y)\}$.

To summarise, it's true that $x\cup\{\varnothing\}$ doesn't immediately contradict the axiom of regularity. But since set theory is not *just* the axiom of regularity, but includes a lot of other axioms, it's easy to see that it *does* lead to a contradiction, it simply takes an ever so slightly longer proof.

Comment: You mean that the seperation, togather with regularity, should rule out $x'$ as a set ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. Or, for example, the fact that we can pick two distinct elements of $x'$, and at least one of them must be non-empty, and it contradicts AR all by itself. Set theory is not just about "this one set", but also about all the sets around it.

Comment: But how should ruling out subsets of $x'$ (if that what you mean) rule out $x'$ itself ? that is exactly what I want to understand

Comment: You are assuming that a something exists, and that you can use it to conclude something else also exist (as a consequence of your other axioms). This is just logical inference. If the something else leads to a contradiction, then either your axioms for constructing it are contradictory, or your initial assumption is.

Comment: @Physor The line of argument is: "Suppose a set with property $P$ existed. Then by Separation, a set with property $Q$ would have to exist. By Regularity, there is no set with property $Q$; so there must not have been a set with property $P$ to begin with." Here property $P$ is your description of $x'$, and property $Q$ is "is an element of itself."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks a lot, that was it!, I think you meant "a **sub**set with property Q would have to exist" right ?

Comment: @Physor Nope! Although in this case the "problematic set" we construct is a subset of the starting set, that isn't necessary in general: once you produce a set with a property you know can't occur, you know that the assumption you made originally was wrong. I was deliberately phrasing things generally rather than focusing on the specifics of this particular case.

Comment: @Physor, nice question, because the axiom of regularity range over ALL sets in the universe of discourse, that is the $``\forall x"$ that you wrote in the sentence of regularity, this quantifier range over *all* sets of the universe of disocurse, now if $x$ is a set of the universe of discourse, then by separation $x \setminus 0$ is also a set in the universe of discourse, and the latter would clearly negate Regularity. That's why ruling out subsets of $x'$ leads to ruling out $x'$ itself, because existence of $x'$ is proving the existence of something that is rule out, so $x'$ cannot exist!